# Substring não retorna string vazia

Tags: string, kotlin, substring

Tenho o seguinte arquivo de texto chamado `fullResponse`

```
<Sum> [stat]player_ammo_restored  = 3447
<Sum> [stat]player_climb_assists  = 2102
<Sum> [stat]player_climb_coops  = 2612
<Sum> [stat]player_damage  = 25129585
```

Existem mais linhas, esse é o começo do arquivo.
Preciso fazer uma `substring` pra pegar os dados. Fazendo

```
   val player_ammo_restored = fullResponse
       .substringAfter("<Sum> [stat]player_ammo_restored  = ")
       .substringBefore("\n<Sum>").toInt()
```

Funciona, e ele traz o valor 3447.
Mas se por exemplo, se a linha `<Sum> [stat]player_climb_assists  = 2102` não existir e eu tentar fazer

```
val player_climb_assists  = fullResponse
    .substringAfter("<Sum> [stat]player_climb_assists  = ")
    .substringBefore("\n<Sum>").toInt()
```

ele retorna a primeira linha do arquivo e dá erro na conversão pra int pq ao invés de trazer o valor ele traz a linha completa (`<Sum> [stat]player_ammo_restored  = 3447`)

Como fazer que o `substring` traga uma string vazia se não existir a linha que estou pesquisando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-after.html), o método `substringAfter` recebe como segundo parâmetro a string a ser retornada caso o delimitador não seja encontrado (e se este parâmetro não é passado, ele retorna a própria string).

Então bastaria fazer algo do tipo:

```
val tmp = fullResponse.substringAfter("<Sum> [stat]player_climb_assists  = ", "")

if (tmp.isEmpty()) {
    print("Não tem player_climb_assists")
} else {
    val player_climb_assists = tmp.substringBefore("\n<Sum>").toInt()
    print(player_climb_assists)
}
```

Ou seja, `.substringAfter("<Sum> [stat]player_climb_assists  = ", "")` retorna uma string vazia caso o trecho " [stat] etc..." não seja encontrado.

Depois basta verificar se foi realmente retornado vazio (pois entendi que neste caso não há valor a ser convertido para número), e só se não for vazio, aí você prossegue e procura pelo número.

---

Dito isso, acho que um jeito mais fácil é ler o arquivo e processá-lo linha a linha. Algo assim:

```
File("fullResponse").forEachLine {
    val valor = it.split("= ")[1].toInt()
    if (it.startsWith("<Sum> [stat]player_ammo_restored")) {
        val player_ammo_restored = valor
        // usar o player_ammo_restored...
    } else if (it.startsWith("<Sum> [stat]player_climb_assists")) {
        val player_climb_assists = valor
        // usar o player_climb_assists...
    } else etc...
}
```

Eu acho essa abordagem melhor porque você não precisa carregar todo o conteúdo do arquivo de uma vez, em uma única string. E também porque o outro método pode falhar se você quiser pegar o valor da última linha (já que não haverá um `\n<Sum>` depois, então `substringBefore` retornará o número seguido da quebra de linha, caso o arquivo termine com uma).

Comment: perfeito, era exatamente isso